# SugarCRM Use REST API With Custom Module

Tags: php, rest, sugarcrm

I created a custom module in SugarCRM (V7.8 I think, hosted, not on premise)

The module is named "Customers", and is for testing purposes - I made the structure the same as "Accounts".

I'm using the example on this page: http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.6/API/Web_Services/Examples/v10/module_POST/

When I run the code for the Accounts module it works.  When I try to POST a record to the Customers module I get:

```
[error] => no_method
[error_message] => Could not find a route with 1 elements
```

My understanding is that the APIs are supposed to work for custom modules, is this incorrect?  My ultimate goal is to create 5 or 6 custom modules and push data into them from our ERP system in real time via the REST APIs.

Here's the example code:

```
<?php
$base_url = "https://my.domain/rest/v10";
$username = "admin";
$password = "*********";
function call($url,$oauthtoken='',$type='GET',$arguments=array(),$encodeData=true,$returnHeaders=false){
    $type = strtoupper($type);
    if ($type == 'GET')
    {
        $url .= "?" . http_build_query($arguments);
    }
    $curl_request = curl_init($url);
    if ($type == 'POST')
    {
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    }
    elseif ($type == 'PUT')
    {
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    }
    elseif ($type == 'DELETE')
    {
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    }
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HEADER, $returnHeaders);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    if (!empty($oauthtoken))
    {
        $token = array("oauth-token: {$oauthtoken}","Content-Type: application/json");
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $token);
    }
    if (!empty($arguments) && $type !== 'GET')
    {
        if ($encodeData)
        {
            //encode the arguments as JSON
            $arguments = json_encode($arguments);
        }
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arguments);
    }
    $result = curl_exec($curl_request);
    if ($returnHeaders)
    {
        //set headers from response
        list($headers, $content) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result ,2);
        foreach (explode("\r\n",$headers) as $header)
        {
            header($header);
        }
        //return the nonheader data
        return trim($content);
    }
    curl_close($curl_request);
    //decode the response from JSON
    $response = json_decode($result);
    return $response;
}

//Login - POST /oauth2/token
$url = $base_url . "/oauth2/token";
$oauth2_token_arguments = array(
    "grant_type" => "password",
    //client id/secret you created in Admin > OAuth Keys
    "client_id" => "sugar",
    "client_secret" => "",
    "username" => $username,
    "password" => $password,
    "platform" => "base"
);
$oauth2_token_response = call($url, '', 'POST', $oauth2_token_arguments);
//Create record - POST /<module>/
$url = $base_url . "/Customers";  //works id this is "Accounts"
$record_arguments = array(
    "name" => "ACME Inc.",
    "description" => "Not for Coyotes"
);
$record_response = call($url, $oauth2_token_response->access_token, 'POST', $record_arguments);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($record_response);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom modules will have a prefix key to avoid conflicts, so rather than `$url =  $base_url . "/Customers";` it will be something like `$base_url . "/xxx_Customers";`.
If you developed the module, you should know the prefix key used, otherwise check the DB schema or Studio/Module Builder

Comment: I went back and searched the documentation and I found this: "Key : The key is an alphanumeric text to distinguish modules with similar names. The system will prefix all class names, directories, and table names with this key."  This turned out to be the prefix you indicated.  I think the documentation could probably be a little clearer.  Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score -1):

Ensure your prefix to the module, also check your endpoint method by hitting this URL for required API method and parameter: `yourdomain/rest/v10/help`.